# Update certain cells from another Sheets according to a criteria in Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a Budget calculator spreadsheet in Google Drive, I'm trying to update cells from another Sheet with certain criteria:

This is Sheet1:

[image]

According to the date and category should update a cell from another Sheet in the same document, with the quantity.

This is Sheet2: [image]

I'm not sure If I'm able to implement this flow in the same Google spreadsheets or if I should use Python instead. I tried everything and I'm stuck here. If someone could give me a hint about it I'll appreciate it a lot.

Here's the link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BEtKJGVOdVF8PLxcR_96cPjE_4XH0QFbtV9dynroly0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'd suggest using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) for this. In any case, can you provide more information about what you tried, what specific issues you encountered, any formula you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

try this cobra query in B13:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A13:A21, QUERY({Sheet2!A3:D; 
 TO_DATE(SEQUENCE(12, 1, 2, 33)), 0/SEQUENCE(12, 3,,)}, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col4) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot month(Col1)-1"), SEQUENCE(1, 12, 2), )))
```

[image]

Comment: what makes it a "cobra"? :)

Comment: @MattKing OP mentioned python so https://youtu.be/lpVQ3oCsjHY :)